# MongoDb fulltext search AND condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I try to use text-index in mongodb:
`{$text: {$search: 'sport hockey'}}`

Is uses OR condition for searching by phrase: 'sport' OR 'hockey'. For example the result can be the following list of titles:

- Sport something today...
- Sport is hockey
- Hockey players

The most relevant document is on the second position (actually I'd like to exclude all other results except this one: 'Sport is hockey').
Is it possible to use AND condition in $text?

Quotation marks are not suitable because `{$text: {$search: "\"sport hockey\""}}` uses search by exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text search does not provide this out-of-the-box. But there are two possible workarounds.

1. Use the pre-2.6 solution for text search: Break your text field into individual words and safe the individual words as an array in the same documents. You can then perform a [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) query on that array.
2. Perform separate text-searches for each word and generate the set intersection on the application layer.

Answer (score 3):

try to include textScore in your output then sort by it to get most relevant documents (optionally use limit to get top n relevant documents).

```
db.your_collection.find(
  {
    $text: { $search: "sport hockey" }
  }, {
    score: { $meta: "textScore" }
  }
).sort(
  {
    score: { $meta: "textScore" }
  }
).limit(2)
```

Comment: From MongoDB Manual: `$text will tokenize the search string using whitespace and most punctuation as delimiters, and perform a logical OR of all such tokens in the search string.`
This means your answer uses `OR` instead of `AND`, which means it didn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

use as Follow

**db.your_collection.find({$text:{$search:' "sport" "hockey" '}})**

> "text" type search word must be included!

Comment: This is working great, but introducing AND operating like this will make your query extremely slow (especially if you have maany records).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this thread again, required search criteria of "AND" can be achieved using following find query

```
{$text:{$search:"\"sport\" \"hockey\""}}
```

Give attention to how different words are escaped.

In node js, following can be done to create desire search text for "AND" condition

```
searchText = '"' + userInput.split(" ").join('" "') + '"';
```

then

```
collectionObj.find({$text:{$search:searchText}})
```